# How to write test case for ErrorBoundary in React using Jest / Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have been trying (without success) to write a test case for `ErrorBoundary` component that is handling errors via componentDidCatch lifecycle method.
Despite the error produced by child component inside the `<ErrorBoundry>` component, `<ErrorBoundry>` does not render info about error in code but the content of faulty component if it would work correct. 
Component works as expected in production/development but not when it is executed by Jest / Enzyme for testing.

Error from testing:

```
 PASS  src/ErrorBoundary.test.js
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
      Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
          in input (at ErrorBoundary.test.js:11)
          in div (at ErrorBoundary.test.js:10)
          in ComponentWithError (at ErrorBoundary.test.js:26)
          in ErrorBoundry (created by WrapperComponent)
          in WrapperComponent
    console.log src/ErrorBoundary.test.js:29
      <ErrorBoundry>
        <ComponentWithError>
          <div>
            <input type="text" value={{...}} />
          </div>
        </ComponentWithError>
      </ErrorBoundry>
```

ErrorBoundry.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Raven from 'raven-js'
import { Segment, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class ErrorBoundry extends Component {
    state = {
        hasError: false
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        this.setState({ hasError: true })
        Raven.captureException(error, { extra: info });
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.hasError) {
            return (
                <div className='error-boundry'>
                    <Segment>
                        <h2> Oh no! Somethin went wrong </h2>
                        <p>Our team has been notified, but click  
                            <Button  onClick={() => Raven.lastEventId() && Raven.showReportDialog()}> 
                            here </Button> to fill out a report.
                        </p>
                    </Segment>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return this.props.children;
        }
    }
}
```

ErrorBoundry.test.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary'

class ComponentWithError extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type = "text" value = {null}/>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}

describe('<ErrorBoundary> window',()=> {
  it('should match the snapshot', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<ErrorBoundary>Test</ErrorBoundary> ).toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('displays error message on error generated by child', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <ErrorBoundary > 
        <ComponentWithError />
      </ErrorBoundary> 
      )
    console.log(wrapper.debug() )
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you try this as the error component `const ComponentWithError = ()=> {    throw new Error()}`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle That worked for me well.

Answer (score 23):

Enzyme has [`simulateError`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulateError.html) helper now.

So this works very well for me:

```
const Something = () => null;

describe('ErrorBoundary', () => {
  it('should display an ErrorMessage if wrapped component throws', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Something />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );

    const error = new Error('test');

    wrapper.find(Something).simulateError(error);

    /* The rest fo your test */
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, it also suppresses any error messages for you so your test output remains clean :)

Answer (score 8):

After additional research I found that it is an open issue that has to be solved by Enzyme. https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1255

I have implemented it as follows:

```
function ProblemChild() {
  throw new Error('Error thrown from problem child');
  return <div>Error</div>; // eslint-disable-line
}

describe('<ErrorBoundary> window',()=> {  
  it('displays error message on error generated by child', () => {
    const spy = sinon.spy(ErrorBoundary.prototype, 'componentDidCatch')
    mount(<ErrorBoundary><ProblemChild /></ErrorBoundary>)
    chaiExpect(ErrorBoundary.prototype.componentDidCatch).to.have.property('callCount', 1)
  })
})
```

Proposed workaround works anyhow

1. it is still not possible to test error message rendered to the app user by `<ErrorBoundary>`
2. test console displays warnings:

   `PASS  src/ErrorBoundary.test.js`
    `● Console`

   ```
   console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9627
     The above error occurred in the <ProblemChild> component:
         in ProblemChild (at ErrorBoundary.test.js:37)
         in ErrorBoundry (created by WrapperComponent)
         in WrapperComponent

     React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundry.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Andreas Köberle's comment since the `hasError` state changes on `ComponentDidCatch` lifecycle method, you could also use enzymes [setState](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.md).

You also don't need to `mount` the comment, `shallow would do`.

```
  it('displays error message on error generated by child', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <ErrorBoundary > 
        <ComponentWithError />
      </ErrorBoundary> 
    );
    wrapper.setState({ hasError: true });
    wrapper.toMatchSnapshot()
  });
```

Comment: What is your assertion for this?

Comment: Add at least .toMatchSnapshot(); and with setSate it'll be fine